# A link isn't working in IE6

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, hyperlink, href

I'm working on the following page: http://jlecologia.com/index.php

I want the *whole* block at the left to be clickable. In Firefox it's fine, but in IE6 the cursor doesn't even change to a hand. Any ideas?

Comment: Chrome isn't cooperating either, just so you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend that you move the block styling (like you're doing with the LI) to the actual link itself. So for example (copied from your stylesheet)...

```
#left ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#left ul li a {
    width: 100%; /* You might not need this */
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(../images/button-fond.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```